# How can a servlet do a hot re-deploy of itself

Tags: java, tomcat

Is there a way for a Servlet to do a hot re-deploy the webapp it is part of?

I know that I can configure Tomcat to do a hot re-deploy on changes to web.xml but I can't find any way to do the same from java code. I don't want tomcat to having to watch the web.xml for changes all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it can be done using JMX.

```
The Tomcat Manager is a web application that can be used interactively (via HTML GUI) or programmatically (via URL-based API) to deploy and manage web applications.
```

There is the link - http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/deployer-howto.html

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

A Servlet has a life cycle that depends on the container. This is explained here 
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnafi.html

What this means is from the web.xml the container figures out a match depending on a request and if there is such a class that exists it loads it as a classloader resource. Once this has happened the instance stays loaded till the container is shutdown so replacing .class files wont actually achieve the "hot-deploy" unless you set the reloadable flag in the tomcat's context.xml
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/context.html#Common_Attributes

In any case, Tomcat or not, once a resource has been loaded by a ClassLoader changing the .class files wont exactly change the behaviour of the running jvm which you would probably know. So even deleting the class files from the file system also wont affect the running java process in ordinary situations.

However it may be possible that a servlet can start a background task that does a basic file copy  of the new .class files you want to 'hot deploy' (if the context attribute 'reloadable' is true). This then forces these classes to be reloaded and so you achieve a hot deploy. So although this is out of the scope of what a servlet is designed to achieve the answer is yes.

Hope this helps.